# jQuery jrac and jQuery .hide() .show() conflict error

Tags: jquery

I am using  [jQuery Resize and Crop (jrac)](http://www.trepmag.ch/z/jrac/example/) . Every thing work fine in my sample code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KpFwb/5/).

But when I try to hide Div area which is showing Image Editor, I found error.
I use below code to hide my div.

```
 $('#ImageZone').hide();
```

Upper code actually work, it hide what i want to hide. But after I call below code, error start happen.

```
$('#ImageZone').show(some int value);
```

It display [incorrect value](http://jsfiddle.net/SMTDc/5/) like below

[image]

But after I remove below code, [everything work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/KpFwb/5/) again.

```
$('#ImageZone').hide();
```

[image]

So let me know what is that error.
Is that jquery error ?
or somthing esle ?

Comment: Which browser are you using? The one linking to "Incorrect Value" seemed fine to me on FF17

Comment: Works fine in my chrome and IE8

Comment: @Rohit Patel and Jeff Watkins, please click this http://jsfiddle.net/SMTDc/5/ and click show image editor button and pull Scrollbar down and check whether you see zero values. If so, it is in error status.

Comment: It's absolutely fine on FF17, which browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

My hunch would be:

- Use `<input type="number"` instead of text (acceptable in html5 http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp)
- Give each `<td><input` an id.
- Before you show the whole div, populate each `<td><input id = "my_id"` with the value to be displayed e.g. `$("#my_id").val(some int value);`